# convert string from textarea to request headers

Tags: javascript, http-headers

I try to make a form that submits a request and posts the result in the page. I have inputs for request body, url and headers. But I have an issue with the headers. I don't know how to convert the string:

```
Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

to

```
{"Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
```

dynamically. In my textarea I might have 3-4 hearers splitted by a comma, so how to convert those headers to an structure that will be accepted by this function:

```
function makePostRequest(url, data, headers, httpVerb, dataType, elementId){
    alert(headers);
    $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: httpVerb,
    data: data,
    headers: {headers},
    dataType: dataType,
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      $("#div").val(jqXHR.responseText);
    },
    error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) { $("#div").val(jqXHR.responseText); }
    });
}
```

My textarea element may contain headers like:

```
header1 : content1, header2 : content2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you, basically it's a combination of split() and trim(). Here's an example:

```js
$(function () {
  $('button').on('click', function (e) {
    var headers = {}
    var values = $('#foo').val()
    
    // split the headers by comma
    var parts = values.split(',')
    
    // iterate over each group
    $.each(parts, function () {
      // split by : and trim additional whitespace
      var innerParts = this.split(':').map(function (item) {
        return item.trim()
      })
      
      // add the given results to the headers object
      headers[innerParts[0]] = innerParts[1]
    })
    
    console.log(headers)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="foo" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
<br>
<button>click me</button>
```

Comment: yes, I want something like this, but using this in my request, if  I use: headers:JSON.stringify( headers) or headers: headers, the headers that I have in my text area are ignored and only preflight request is made(with OPTIONS http verb)

Comment: Don't stringify the headers, it's supposed to be an object

Comment: nope, still the same. But I will make some further researches. the function that you provided it's working, so I will mark the answer as accepted. Thanks

Comment: This line `headers: {headers},` in your code should be  `headers: computedHeaders`, where `computedHeaders` is the result of that function

Comment: The problem was with f**king CORS... I add ed Access-Control-Allow-Headers header in the response from mocky and now it works...

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood, before to do the $ajax request, you can get the headers and parse it yourself to create a string like what you want. You can use regex to split headers when you have more than one.

Comment: I was able also to write pseudocode to, but I don't have experience with javascjript, that's why I've asked

Comment: Is your var  headers an assoc array ?

Comment: I don't know what it should be... now I've hardcoded a value, but I don't have experience with javascript types, so I can't answer your question. What I need is a function that converts a string to my headers varuiable so I can fit it in the request, as you can see in the source code

Answer (score 0):

This is not really about headers, this is just string manipulation:
you need to turn

```
"header1 : content1, header2 : content2"
```

into

```
{"header1": "content1", "header2": "content2"}
```

By splitting the first string with the `,` character and then splitting all the substrings with `:` it should be ok.

Comment: I was able also to write pseudocode to, but I don't have experience with javascjript, that's why I've asked

Answer (score 0):

Does something Like this work for you?
It basically expects each header to be entered in a new line:

```js
function getHeaders() {
  var headers = $('#headers').val();
  var lines = headers.split('\n');
  var headers = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    
    var line = lines[i];
    var parts = line.split(':');
    var key = parts[0];
    var value = parts[1];
    if (key && value) {
      headers[key.trim()] = value.trim();
    }
  }
  return headers
}

$('button').click(function(){
  var headersObject = getHeaders();
  console.log(headersObject);
})
```

```css
#headers {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="headers">
Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Header2 : Value
</textarea>
<button>Get Headers Object</button>
```